# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

Tags: c, valgrind

```
==13890== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13890==    at 0x4E7E4F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==13890==    by 0x4E878D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==13890==    by 0x400729: main (001.c:30)
==13890==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13890==    at 0x400617: main (001.c:11)
```

The line being referenced:

```
int limit = atoi(argv[1]);
```

I am not sure how to fix it.  I have tried searching on stackoverflow and google but I could not find the solution.

The code (from revision history):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("You must pass a single integer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int limit = atoi(argv[1]); 
    int numbers[limit / 2];
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 3; i < limit; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            numbers[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show more code. Problem.is almost certainly somewhere else.

Comment: Line 30 is `return 0;`, and there's no reason for that line to have anything printf-related. I get the feeling this valgrind output isn't synchronised with the code.

Comment: @Bart Judging by Bart's answer's and the OP's comments on it, you edited the *fixed* code into the question; code which no longer demonstrates the problem. That's not helpful.

Comment: Seems like it @andrew. I must have missed that back then. Unfortunately the original link is dead, so I see no way to correct the situation.

Comment: It's a shame the code was edited in as an external link which has become stale and thus irrelevant to the question. Despite being a source of reputation for me (see below), I'm going to vote to close (and perhaps later delete) this, because it can't possibly be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Link isn't working any more, provide the code that was causing issues

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you checked `argc` and the contents of `argv[1]`? Is `argv[1]` guaranteed to be non-`NULL` in order to be suitable as input for `atoi`? Is it possible that `atoi` might be returning a trap representation representing an uninitialised value, due to `argv[1]` being non-numeric?

*edit*: After seeing the complete code, I've realised that that's not the problem, and your diagnosis is incorrect. Your problem is here: `for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) { sum += numbers[i]; }` When`i == count`, `numbers[i]` is uninitialised. This is because count is incremented after the last assignment to `numbers[count]` in the previous loop: `numbers[count] = i; count++;`. Hence, printing sum results in your message because sum itself depends upon an uninitialised value. Perhaps you meant `for (i = 0; i < count; i++) { sum += numbers[i]; }`

Comment: I was passing in "10", like this: `./001 10`.  Also, the program DOES work but I just want to know why I am getting that error.  I will edit in the link to the full code.

Answer (score 0):

int limit = atoi(argv[1])
Declare it first with init value and then use it.