# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation when calling different function

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

The code below:

```
Board* constructBoard(int dimension)
{
    //Allocate memory for board
    Board *board = malloc(sizeof(Board));
    if(!board)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    //Allocate memory for matrix
    board->matrix = malloc(dimension * sizeof(int*));
    if(!board->matrix)
    {
        freeBoard(board);
        return NULL;
    }
    //Allocate memory for each row of matrix
    for(int row = 0; row < dimension; row++)
    {
        // Following line is line 29 from error below  <---------------------------
        board->matrix[row] = malloc(dimension * sizeof(int));  
        if(!board->matrix[row])
        {
            freeBoard(board);
            return NULL;
        }
        board->dimension = row +1;
    }
    board->value = 0;
    return board;
}

void printBoard(Board *board, char* delimiter)
{
    assert(board && "printBoard must get an initialized board");
    for(int i = 0; i < board->dimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board->dimension; j++)
        {
            printf("%d%s", board->matrix[i][j], delimiter);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When called from main like this:

```
Board *final = constructBoard(4);
printBoard(final, SEPARATOR);
freeBoard(final);
```

Results in the following valgrind error (See comment in code above for line of error):

```
==8450==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==8450==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8450==    by 0x401560: constructBoard (Board.c:29)
==8450==    by 0x400FAB: main (SudokuSolver.c:181)
```

Definition of `Board`:

```
typedef struct Board
{
    int** matrix;
    int dimension;
    unsigned int value;
} Board;
```

When I do not add the call to `printBoard` everything is fine.

1. Why do I get the error only when I use `printBoard`?
2. Why when I get the error it says it is in the `constructBoard`?

I've read these previous questions but I still didn't manage to solve it as I properly allocated the memory and made sure loops iterate only valid indexes:

1. [Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15049033/6400526)
2. [Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation - valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33980958/6400526)
3. [Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26190881/6400526)

I've compiled with the following flags:

```
gcc -g -c -Wextra -Wall -Wvla -DNDEBUG -std=c99
```

Comment: `as I properly initialized the data`... how do you make that claim?

Comment: On an unrelated note, [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) is a preprocessor macro that only does something if `NDEBUG` is *not* defined. Don't use it for run-time validation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - not counting on it for run-time exactly for that reason :)

Comment: If you hit this condition `if(!board->matrix[row])` you should also `free` the memory for the previous rows and for `board->matrix`.

Comment: @Gerhardh - It takes place in the `freeBoard`

Comment: How do you determine in `freeBoard` which elements `board->matrix[row]` need to be free'd? You don't have the `dimension`set yet and you don't know how far `row` counted.

Comment: @Gerhardh - if the allocating of the row succeeded then I set the dimension as `board->dimension = row +1;` (checked it at a later point after posting question - will update)

Comment: If you also set initial value for dimention it might work. BTW: Questions shouldn't be changed invalidating the comments. No one likes moving targets!

Comment: @Gerhardh - agree but this case is of something not related to the main purpose of the question - the malloc vs calloc is as was when posted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function only allocates memory, it does not initialize that memory in any way. The contents of the memory is *indeterminate*.

You print the contents of this uninitialized memory in the `printBoard` function, leading to the warning you get.

If you want to initialize the memory, then either do it explicitly or use [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) to allocate and "clear" (zero) the memory (it's equivalent to `malloc` followed by `memset`).